# Confused by globalCompositeOperation

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to program a simple demo of the first few iterations of a Sierpinski Carpet like so:

[image: Sierpinski Carpet]

The way I want to proceed is by clicking to apply the basic pattern mask on a smaller scale each step. It seems to me that by starting with a black square, and then using a globalCompositeOperation of "destination-in" and a source mask just like the second image I should be able to do what I want, but I'm struggling to put it together.

This draws the background black square:

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

And then I expected code like the following should produce the first step.  But instead it just goes blank.

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
var mask = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1];
for (var m = 0; m < 9; ++m)
{
    var x = 10 + m % 3 * 150;
    var y = 10 + Math.floor(m / 3) * 150;
    if (mask[m] > 0)
    {
        context.fillRect(x, y, 150, 150);
    }
}
```

I've put together a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/128gxxmy/4/ to show the problem.

It really doesn't seem to be a difficult thing to do, so I've clearly misunderstood something significant and will be grateful for any advice.

Thanks.

Edit:  Of course!  I know why it goes blank. The first fill rect clears all but the top left corner, and the next one wipes that out.  I need to use rect(...) then fill() in one go.  If I rework it to paint each pass in a single step it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness and in case others fall into the same trap, here's the relevant code.  I ended up using a temporary (invisible) canvas, and drew a whole layer with one fill.

```
function drawLevel(k, fill, mask)
{
    tempContext.save();
    tempContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // current canvas is destination
    tempContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
    // set global composite
    tempContext.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";

    // draw source
    tempContext.beginPath();

    // how many squares each row
    var n = Math.pow(3, k);

    var size = 450 / n / 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (var j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            for (var m = 0; m < 9; ++m)
            {
                var x = 10 + i * size + m % 3 * size;
                var y = 10 + j * size + Math.floor(m / 3) * size;
                if (mask[m] > 0)
                {
                    tempContext.rect(x, y, size, size);
                }
            }
        }

    tempContext.fillStyle = fill;
    tempContext.fill();
    tempContext.restore();

    // copy drawing from tempCanvas onto visible canvas
    context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
}
```